# Confusion in proof of Inverse Laplace Transform

Tags: transform, laplace-transform

For the proof of inverse Laplace transform, we change the integral from $\omega$ to $s$. I want to know the reason why we need to change the integral?
[image]

Comment: Your question is very vague.  I have never seen the change of variable you describe. Can you point to an example? Often, the substitution $s = \sigma + j \omega$ is used, but never $s = \omega$.

Comment: I have saw this in the book , Signals and Systems by Alan Oppenheim

Comment: Nowhere does Oppenheim use the substitution $s  = \omega$, because it is nonsensical.  Please check the notes [here](http://ocw.mit.edu/resources/res-6-007-signals-and-systems-spring-2011/lecture-notes/MITRES_6_007S11_lec20.pdf) especially page 3 of the PDF.  You will see the substitution is $s = \sigma + j \omega$.

Comment: in this PDF they didnt mentioned anything about Inverse Laplace Transform

Comment: I have added the snap from the book

Comment: The text plainly says it's the inverse **Fourier** transform, not *Laplace* that they are performing in equation (9.35). The reason is that the Fourier and Laplace transforms are related: the Fourier transform is the Laplace transform evaluated on the imaginary axis of $s = \sigma + j \omega$ (i.e. $\sigma = 0$.

Comment: @PeterK. can you please this [question](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/27287/laplace-transform-of-e-atu-t)

Comment: @PeterK. you mean that we were using inverse Fourier transform equation to proof the equation for inverse Laplace transform. as  inverse Fourier transform was depending only on imaginary axis, so we changed to complex axis ($s= \sigma +j\omega$)for  inverse Laplace transform? is it correct what i have understand?

Comment: Correct! That's what they're doing in that screenshot.

Comment: Got it..and similarly the $d\omega$ part is changed. taking the derivative of complex axis $ds=d\sigma + j d\omega$.. as $\sigma$ is constant so it will be zero so we will left with $ds= j d\omega$ right?

Comment: @PeterK. is it correct, i used the term derivative? if it is correct than we will take derivative w.r.t ????

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32109/discussion-between-peter-k-and-aadnan-farooq-a).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the discussion:

- The usual substitution is $s = \sigma + j \omega$ where $\sigma$ is the real part of the $s$ variable and $\omega$ is the imaginary part.
- The equation in the image is for the **Fourier** transform, not the **Laplace** transform. The Fourier transform can be thought of as the Laplace transform evaluated on the imaginary axis ($\sigma = 0$).
- The differential $ds$, when looking at real and imaginary parts distinctly, becomes $d\sigma + j d\omega$.
- Any **differential** is an infinitesimal (very small) change in that variable. $dx$ is a small change in $x$.